# Setting Selected Style in AJAX Control Toolkit - TabContainer

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I am using a tabContainer in my page, and I have set the HeaderTemplete - e.g:

```
<cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" CssClass="tab">

        <cc1:TabPanel ID="ListView" runat="server" HeaderText="List View">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label style="padding:2px;" Width="100px" ID="ListHeader" runat="server" 
                CssClass="tdheader" Text="List View"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
           </ContentTemplate>
        </cc1:TabPanel>
        <cc1:TabPanel ID="MapView" runat="server" HeaderText="Map View">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label style="padding:2px;" Width="100" ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="tdheader" Text="Map View"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </cc1:TabPanel>
        </cc1:TabContainer>
```

How can set the style of the Active tab, i.e. I want the active tab to be blue and the rest of the tabs as grey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS class for the tabs, use the ajax__tab_active class.  Take a look at [the Tabs example page](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx) for a list of CSS classes that can be applied to the Tabs control.

I took my tabs theme from [Matt Berseth's site](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/five_ajaxcontroltoolkit_tab_th.html), and he uses these classes in his sample code.